# How to do an inline query with the last inserted records as per month selection?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query and getting the history data on the bases of providing date.

A history have many records added in the same month with same parameters but with a different date (in the same month or can be in different months).

If the selected month is January 2019 then last added records (in the history) should be shown.

and if the selected month is December 2019 then the last inserted records(in the history) in the month of December 2019 records should be shown and so on.

We have to fix it through inline query.

This is for a SQL Server 2014. I have tried to develop the logic with partition by over function. 
See my tried query but each time it is getting very first records rather than last inserted records.

```
    Declare @pDtFrom datetime = '2019-01-01';
Declare @pDtTo datetime = '2019-01-31 23:59:59';
Declare @pIntFranchiseId int = 16179;


select BA.Id AS AgreementId, VC.Name AS VehicleCategory, BA.RentalAgreementId AS AgreementNumber, BI.InvoiceNumber As InvoiceNumber, BI.InvoiceType as InvoiceType, BI.CreatedOn as CreatedOn,                                                     
               (CASE WHEN VC.Id = 8 THEN
                0
                ELSE
               Round(CAST(
               (Select TFrVCRatesHis.PracticalRate FROM (SELECT  VCR.PracticalRate, 
               row_number() over(partition by VCR.Franchise_Id,VCR.VehicleCatg_Id, VCR.Franchise_VCRatesId  order by VCR.Id desc, VCR.ProcessingDate DESC) as rn
                FROM Franchise_VCRatesHistory VCR WHERE VCR.Franchise_Id = @pIntFranchiseId AND VCR.VehicleCatg_Id = F.VehicleCategory_id and VCR.ProcessingDate <= @pDtTo  
               ) TFrVCRatesHis where TFrVCRatesHis.rn = 1)
                AS float),2) 
               END) AS PracticalRate,                           

               (CASE WHEN VC.Id = 8 THEN
                0
                ELSE
               Round(CAST((SELECT VCR.COIRate FROM Franchise_VCRates VCR WHERE VCR.Franchise_Id = @pIntFranchiseId AND VCR.VehicleCatg_Id = F.VehicleCategory_id) AS float),2) 
               END) AS COIRate
        from BKInvoices BI
        join BookingAgreements BA on BA.Id = BI.AgreementId
        JOIN Franchise FA ON FA.Id = BA.FranchiseId 
        JOIN Fleets F ON F.Id = BA.FleetId 
        JOIN VehicleCategories VC ON VC.Id = F.VehicleCategory_id 
        where (BI.NetHireAmount>0 or (BI.NetHireAmount=0 and  (select COUNT(BKE.Id) from BKExtras BKE join Extras E on E.Id=BKE.ExtraId where BKE.AgreementId=BI.AgreementId and E.Code='CH')=0)) and BI.CreatedOn>=@pDtFrom and BI.CreatedOn<=@pDtTo AND BA.FranchiseId = @pIntFranchiseId AND BA.StatusId = 1 AND BA.BKIsOwnInsurance = 0 And BI.InvoiceType=1
```

I want to get the last inserted records (from history) in selected month.

Comment: ORDER BY BI.CreatedOn DESC at the end of it, and SELECT TOP 5 .. at the start of it - does that do it?

Comment: no. it can be many.  I am using order by with partition by